# Create a Google Chrome extension to set new tabs to a local HTML file and stylesheet

Tags: html, json, google-chrome

I'm trying to make an extension for Chrome to make new tabs load a local HTML file. I have partially succeeded in this, by adding a .json file to the main directory with the following code:

```
{
 "name": "Extension Name",
 "description": "Extension description",
 "version": "0.1",
 "incognito": "split",
 "chrome_url_overrides": {
  "newtab": "start.html"
 },
 "manifest_version": 2
}
```

This sort of works. Opening a new tab loads the HTML file, but the majority of the css doesn't work and none of the images load.

I don't want to install an extension from the web store to do this for me, as I would like to be able to distribute this in the future.

I have no experience at all with Google Chrome extensions, and I couldn't find anything relating to this specific issue elsewhere. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Do I need to be do something else? Is this possible? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hey, @Intelta, it should work. You just need to point css files and image files.

Answer (score 3):

let me share I've made shortly.

This is the same manifest file you'd mentioned above

```
{
     "name": "Extension Name",
     "description": "Extension description",
     "version": "0.1",
     "incognito": "split",
     "chrome_url_overrides": {
      "newtab": "start.html"
     },
     "manifest_version": 2
}
```

I created a folder named **assets** in the root directory of chrome extension (that has the `manifest.json` file), where I created `style.css` and added an image file `img.jpg`.

```css
.content p {
    font-size: 26px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">
    <p>Hello world</p>
    <img src="assets/image.jpg">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This works on my end.
I hope it would give you a hind on what went wrong there.

Thanks,

Comment: Ok, I've worked out what's happening. Images still load, but the background image doesn't because I set it through JavaScript. None of my JavaScript works, which messed with my formatting, which is where I got confused. Does chrome block it for security or something?

Comment: When you place the background image, what url have you used? There is a specific chrome api to get assets url. 
`chrome.extension.getURL('assets/image.jpg')`
Please try with this. Or you can share you js code to set background image.

Comment: Noted, thank you. I'll try that as soon as I get to my computer. However, there were a few other functions in a different <script> tag that provided the date and time etc, and they didn't work either. It could be that the background thing was causing an error, though. I'll try tomorrow. Thanks,